# DevTools could not find /lightbox-plus-jquery.min.map: System error: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: lightbox

hello i added jquery lighbox into my image gallery page but when i opened the developer tools to make my webpage responsive it gives this error [DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for file:///C:/Users/dell/Desktop/image-gallery/html/js/lightbox-plus-jquery.min.map: System error: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND]
i located the jquery.min.map file in lighbox folder and added it in same path to my index.html it stopped giving this error but still i cant make my webpage responsive after using jquery lighbox.i want to make my webpage responsive for screens <600px width what should i do? I am a beginner level developer so please any easy solution.
@media screen and (max-width:600px){} this works fine for making my other webpages responsive where i just used simple javascript and no lightbox.

Answer (score 0):

There is no file lightbox-plus-jquery.min.map
You can download from here
https://land.copernicus.eu/user-corner/technical-library/corine-land-cover-nomenclature-guidelines/js/lightbox-plugin/dist/js/lightbox-plus-jquery.min.map/view

you have to add file in js folder.
Hope it work !!